# Visual C++ error: function must return a value

Tags: c++, visual-c++, unreachable-code

I am working on a multiplatform project, and some platforms have disabled features, and in the interface for those features, a common thing I do is something like this:

```
bool Foo::bar() const {
    // disabled
    abort();
}
```

GCC/LLVM do not require that non-void functions return values (they just give a warning), and in this case, where I call `abort()`, they are smart enough to not even give a warning (since the function will never return anyway).

Is there a way (compile flag?) to make Visual C++ 2010 behave the same way, so I don't keep breaking the Windows build? I know I could always return the value after the abort, but when working on the other platforms I usually forget about that, and the behavior of not giving an error seems more appropriate.

Comment: On the flip side of this, when I *do* include the useless return, it sometimes gives me an "Unreachable Code" warning... lol

Comment: Calling `abort` directly seems like a bad practice. Why not use `assert(false)`?

Comment: @JurajBlaho assert(false) will result in warnings (GCC/LLVM) on the release build.

Comment: ...and depending on the environment, assert(FALSE) may turn into a no-op after the preprocessor has had its way with the sources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you want to disable the error add `/w34716` as compile flag (assuming you are using warning level 3 or higher) - now only a warning is issued (if the warning level is 3 or higher). You could also disable the warning (`/wd4716`), but that is probably no good idea - depending on the number of warnings due to this behaviour.

Answer (score 4):

`__declspec(noreturn)` should have this effect in MSVC++ compilers. I would expect standard `abort` to be declared as `__declspec(noreturn)`. But since compiler generates errors in your example, then it probably isn't declared that way. I would suggest that you check the declaration of `abort`. If it has no `__declspec(noreturn)` in it, you should add it somehow.

Answer (score 2):

In general, the Visual C++ compilers allow you to [annotate a function with `__declspec(noreturn)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6ktzx3s%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) to indicate that the function will never return. This helps the compiler realize that any code after a call to such a function is unreachable.

The problem you're hitting here is covered in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3569643/abort-is-not-declspecnoreturn-in-vs2010).  To make a longer story short, `abort()` doesn't have this annotation in the Visual C++ runtime headers.